# Cannot load image from local file system in Nativescript?

Tags: android, nativescript

I am not able to load local image from file system using Image tag.

```
<Page 
xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onLoaded" navigatedTo="onNavigatedTo">
<StackLayout>
    <Label text="Test above" textWrap="true" />
    <Image src="~/images/Apps-Android-icon.png" stretch="none" />
    <Label text="text below" textWrap="true" />
</StackLayout>
```

This is my view and my images are kept in here :

[image]

It just loads as such without image:

[image]

I refereed the [official docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/images#load-images-from-local-file-system) and it says the same specifications.
What am I doing wrong and why its not loading ?

I am running it in Android emulator <5.1_WVGA_API_22>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images or anything you want to pack with app should be placed inside app folder.